# Div/background image's height to expand, and not be hidden under div below; when width goes over 1776px

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm just getting started on this app, and have run into a (for me) perplexing roadblock...

I'd like the height of div to adjust/expand and maintain pictures aspect ratio, pushing the div below further down for accommodation.  I've tried height: auto, overflow: visible to no avail.

Like i mentioned.. everything's great until the width of webpage goes beyond 1776px, then as background image expands, the bottom of image starts to disappear behind div underneath it.

I've commented out a media query because the transition was unsightly. hoping its something easy, and would be grateful for any assistance; thank you.

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIP7s.png)

JS
[image: JS]

everything's kosher..
[image: everything's kosher..]

until width hits 1776px
[image: until width hits 1776px]

```
CSS: 
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.landing {
  background: url("./images/WHproofbackground.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 95vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}
/* @media only screen and (max-width: 1776px) {
  .landing {
    height: 120vw;
  }
} */

.cabin-background {
}

.welcome {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.second-base {
  height: 100em;
  background-color: #957274;
}

js:

import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="landing">
        <div className="cabin-background">
          <p className="welcome">Welcome Home,</p>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className="second-base">hello</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: In your question you need to provide [code and styles as text, not a screen capture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2516718).

Comment: ok, how bout now?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks anyway.

```
height: calc(0.664 * 100vw);
```